# Beginner issues with HTML and Lua

Tags: html, lua

I've got a Lua program that works on a Linux  device. I access it use a HTML page. My problem is that there not one line of comment on this program so I'm trying to figure out how it works.

```
    <td><span class="menu"><a href="channel/<%= num %>">edit</a><%
            if channel.enabled then
            %><a href="channel/<%= num %>?disable=true">disable</a>
```

Without going deeper in code my problem is `?disable=true`. Who should understand it? The code  between `<%%>` is Lua code and I'm fine with it.

Comment: What's the question here? `?disable=true` is a part of the `href` attribute of the anchor tag.

Comment: when I click on disbable button nothing happens, so I'm wondring what it suppose to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML code you show only display a link which contains either ***edit*** or ***disable***.

The link opens an html/php page which is ***channel/<%=num%>*** when the label is ***edit*** and ***channel/<%=num%>?disable=true*** when the label is ***disable***.

I guess ***<%=num%>*** is replaced by a number which could be anything, an output/input number or whatever a linux device can use or drive.

You didn't make yourself very clear.

Comment: num is the index of the channel but what ?disable=true is what does the "?" do is checking if if disable is true or just try to call a new HTML page

Comment: @Engine It's a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). It's passed in with the URL for the server to do something with.